# Give an asymptotic upper bound for $T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^2log_2n$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

Give an asymptotic upper bound for $$T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^2log_2n$$ Using the recursion tree method, I obtain $$\sum_{i=0}^{log_2n - 1}  \frac{n}{2^i}log_2\frac{n}{2^i} + n^2\theta(1)$$
Not sure how to solve this summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)=4T\left(2^{\log_2 \frac n2}\right)+n^2\log_2 n
$$

making $\mathbb{T}(\cdot) = T(2^{(\cdot)}),\ \ z = \log_2 n$ we have

$$
\mathbb{T}(z) = 4\mathbb{T}(z-1)+z 4^z
$$

This recurrence has the solution

$$
\mathbb{T}(z) = \frac 12 z(z+1)4^z+C_0 4^{z-1}
$$

and backtracking we have

$$
T(n) = C_1n^2+\frac 12(\log_2 n+1)n^2\log_2 n
$$

then

$$
T(n) \approx \Theta\left((n\log_2 n)^2\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

In
$\sum_{i=0}^{log_2n - 1}  \frac{n}{2^i}log_2\frac{n}{2^i} + n^2\theta(1)
$,
let
$n = 2^m$.

This is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=0}^{m - 1}  2^{m-i}\log_2(2^{m-i}) + 2^{2m}\theta(1)
&=2^m\sum_{i=0}^{m - 1} (m-i) 2^{-i} + 2^{2m}\theta(1)\\
&=2^m(\sum_{i=0}^{m - 1} m 2^{-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{m - 1}i 2^{-i}) + 2^{2m}\theta(1)\\
&=2^m(m(1-2^{-m})-\dfrac{1+O(2^{-m})}{(1-\frac12)^2}) + 2^{2m}\theta(1)\\
&=2^m(m(1-2^{-m})-4+O(2^{-m})) + 2^{2m}\theta(1)\\
&=m2^m + 2^{2m}\theta(1)\\
&=\Theta(n^2)\\
\end{array}
$

So the sum is small compared
to the $n^2$ term.